# Angular Scope Variables not being Updated

Tags: angularjs

I'm fairly new to Angular, but it seems this should work:

HTML:

```
<div style="float:left;width:26%;height:96%;margin:2% 0 2% 0;background-color:#efefef;padding:0 2% 0 2%;" ng-app="fcApp"
     ng-controller="fcCtrl">
<span>Find:</span>
<input id="student_search" type=text
       ng-keypress="selectFirstStudent($event)"
       ng-model="student_search" placeholder="name / ssn">
<div style="max-height:90%;" ng-show="student_search">
    <div style="width:100%;height:30px;"
        ng-repeat="student in students | filter:student_search as filtered"
        ng-click="newStudent(student);">
        {{ student.firstname }} {{ student.lastname }} - {{ student.ssn }}
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div style="float:left;width:70%;">
    <input id="ssn" ng-model="student.ssn">
    {{ student.ssn }}
</div>
```

Controller(partial):

```
$scope.getStudents = function(){
    $http.get('/getstudents/')
        .then(function(response){
            $scope.students = response.data.students;
            $scope.student = $scope.students[0];
        }
    );
};
$scope.getStudents();
```

So the `getStudents` function is obviously working to the extent it actually gets a list of the students from the database.  But all of my `$scope` variables aren't being updated.

As I type part of a name in the input box, the list of students gets properly filtered down, and the list gets shorter.  However, I see no values in the list, only the "-" which should appear between last name and SSN.  That appears on every row of the filtered result.

Didn't supply all code, but when I click on one of the items in the filtered list, I get an alert showing selected student ID and SSN.  So the data is there, it's just not appearing in the Angular variables.  Also, last div should be showing the student SSN twice, right?  Nothing there either.  BTW, clicking the filtered list does fire event which sets `$scope.student` to the student object clicked, as my alert demonstrates.

So why don't I see any of the values, either in the filtered list or the input with `ng-model` set?

Comment: Can you please add codepen ?

Comment: What is codepen?

Comment: https://codepen.io or any other like plunker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using

```
$scope.student = $scope.students[0];
```

inside your method.

And also

```
ng-repeat="student in students | filter:student_search as filtered"
```

Both are same variable so your DOM is not updated.

Try using a different name as below, for example I am using `stud`

```
<div style="max-height:90%;" ng-show="student_search">
    <div style="width:100%;height:30px;"
        ng-repeat="stud in students | filter:student_search as filtered"
        ng-click="newStudent(stud);">
        {{ stud.firstname }} {{ stud.lastname }} - {{ stud.ssn }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Aravind.  Took out the assignment in controller, and changed html as mentioned, but still nothing shows.  As I start typing in the input, I get a long list of dashes, which shortens as I type, as designed.  If I click on one, I get an alert showing the selected student's SSN. so I know something's working.  Just don't know why Angular fields aren't showing.

Comment: Ok, got it figured.  I'm giving you credit because you took the trouble to answer me.  Actual issue was happening because I'm combining Angular and Django, and Django was getting confused by the Angular tags.  Once I put the {% verbatim %} and {% endverbatim %} tags in my html, then it worked.  Should have put that info in my question, it wouldn't have taken so long to figure it out.  Thanks...